# How can I look up words in an eBook reader with Google Translate?

Tags: ebook-reader, translate, google-translate

Is there way  to look up words and phrases while reading an eBook in the Google Translate app? Moon reader can do that in a browser, but the translate app is much better.

---

Here is what I ended up doing:

1. Install Aldiko reader
2. Install Andmade Share
3. Hide all share apps except Google Translate using Andmade
4. Select a phrase in Aldiko
5. Tap on the share button

Now the translation of the phrase will appear directly in the Google Translate app.

Comment: Please note that we prefer questions that ask how to solve a problem, rather than questions that ask for help finding an app. You should have a look at our [help].

Comment: As Al noted: *Is there an app for X* questions are off topic here. However, as Moon+ itself recommends: Install [ColorDict](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialnmobile.colordict) or [Fora Dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ngc.fora) alongside, both integrate fine with Moon+ and support online dictionaries as well as offline dictionaries.

Comment: Google's [Play Books app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.books) integrates translate and you can [upload your own books into it](https://play.google.com/books).  Un-DRMed ePUBs and PDFs are supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ebook reader apps with can enable you to share book passages. And you can use Google Translate to share them... So select the passage and share it using Google Translate ! For example, the [Kobo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kobobooks.android) for Android and Aldiko ([free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aldiko.android) or [€2.49](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.aldiko)) are ebook readers which enable to share book passages. [Google Play Books](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.books) have a built in feature to translate passages too (it must use Google Translate).

Obviously, you can also copy the passages by hand, open the Google Translate app and use it to translate what you have just copied. It is not quite smart or ergonomic but it works.

Comment: Is there a way to set the default app for share?

Comment: @CravingSpirit Perhaps but it is a bad idea. "Share" is used to share everything with every media. From "sharing a text by mail or on a random social network" to "share a file with another device via Bluetooth", they all use the "share" intent. Setting a default app for sharing is not convenient at all. Avoid it and forget this idea.